# How to use "INSERT" in psycopg2 connection pooling?

Tags: python, connection-pooling, psycopg2, psycopg

I use psycopg2 to connect to PostgreSQL on Python and I want to use connection pooling.

I don't know what should I do instead commit() and rollback() when I execute INSERT query.

```
db = pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 10,host=conf_hostname,database=conf_dbname,user=conf_dbuser,password=conf_dbpass,port=conf_dbport)


# Get Cursor
@contextmanager
def get_cursor():
    con = db.getconn()
    try:
        yield con.cursor()
    finally:
        db.putconn(con)


with get_cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) RETURNING id") 
    id = cursor.fetchone()
```

I don't get id of inserted record without commit().

Comment: I found a configuration for commit: "con.autocommit = True", what can I do for rollback()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE**  I can not test the code but I give you some ideas:
You do the commit in connection not in db

```
# Get Cursor
@contextmanager
def get_cursor():
    con = db.getconn()
    try:
        yield con
    finally:
        db.putconn(con)

with get_cursor() as cursor:
    con.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) RETURNING id") 
    con.commit()
    id = cursor.fetchone()
```

or

```
# Get Cursor
@contextmanager
def get_cursor():
    con = db.getconn()
    try:
        yield con.cursor()
        con.commit()
    finally:
        db.putconn(con)


with get_cursor() as cursor:
    con.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) RETURNING id") 
    id = cursor.fetchone()
```

---

Connection pooling exist because creating a new connection to a db can be expensive and not to avoid commits or rollbacks. So you can commit your data without any issue, committing data will not destroy the connection.

Comment: thank you. but how to commit data? db.commit() does not exist!

Comment: or may be I should use "con.commit()" and "con.rollback()", yes?

Comment: yes, "con.commit()" and "con.rollback()" mut be used

Comment: thank you for answer! I have another question about connection pooling. "what happen if I open a connection in my program and don't close it?instead connection pooling". my program runs as a service and listens to a socket for packets. I want to save more than 1000 record per second!

Comment: Connection pooling is for sharing the same connection, instead of opening 100 connections to db I open only one and I use 100 times. Doesn't listen to any socket, is not a service, it is only a client.

Comment: If you will not close the connection, it will remain open until the program is closed or killed.

Answer (score 6):

here is my working example:

```
db = pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 10,host=conf_hostname,database=conf_dbname,user=conf_dbuser,password=conf_dbpass,port=conf_dbport)


@contextmanager
def get_connection():
    con = db.getconn()
    try:
        yield con
    finally:
        db.putconn(con)

def write_to_db():
    with get_connection() as conn:
        try:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) RETURNING id") 
            id = cursor.fetchone()
            cursor.close()
            conn.commit()
        except:
            conn.rollback()
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will be a little more `pythonic`:

```py
db_pool = pool.SimpleConnectionPool(1, 10,
                                    host=CONF.db_host,
                                    database=CONF.db_name, 
                                    user=CONF.db_user, 
                                    password=CONF.db_user,
                                    port=CONF.db_port)


@contextmanager
def db():
    con = db_pool.getconn()
    cur = con.cursor()
    try:
        yield con, cur
    finally:
        cur.close()
        db_pool.putconn(con)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with db() as (connection, cursor):
        try:
            cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table (fields)
VALUES (values) RETURNING id""")
            my_id = cursor.fetchone()
            rowcount = cursor.rowcount
            if rowcount == 1:
                connection.commit()
            else:
                connection.rollback()
        except psycopg2.Error as error:
            print('Database error:', error)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('General error:', ex)
```