# PYTHON: Passing psycopg2 cursor as a parameter to an other class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, parameter-passing, psycopg2

So my goal is to insert data into the database. I have a psycopg2 connection pool in my main code and I want to use one of the pool's connection in an other class so I tried to pass the cursor as a parameter.
Here I create the connection pool:

```
conn_pool = psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool(1, 20, user="",
                                                 password="",
                                                 host="",
                                                 port="",
                                                 database="")
```

Here I call the insert function from the User class.

```
conn = conn_pool.getconn()
cur = conn.cursor()
result = users[thread_id].insert(cur, data)
conn_pool.putconn(conn)
```

And here is the insert function in the User class

```
    def insert(self, cur, data):
        username = data["data"]["username"]
        password = data["data"]["password"]
        cur.execute(f"select user_id from users where username like '{username}'")
        raw = cur.fetchone()
        if raw is not None:
            dataj = {"title": "signup_feedback",
                     "feedback": 0}
            self.connection.send(json.dumps(dataj).encode())
            return False
        print("Signup attempt")
        cur.execute("insert into users (username, password, balance, logged_in) " +
                    f"values ('{username}', '{password}', 5000, false)")
        dataj = {"title": "signup_feedback",
                 "feedback": 1}
        self.connection.send(json.dumps(dataj).encode())
        return True
```

It didn't work. It didn't raise an error, it just didn't do anything. Is there a way to do it? I'm also open for other ideas.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure, just a moment.

Comment: Probably you just need to `commit()` after inserting, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621532/how-to-use-insert-in-psycopg2-connection-pooling

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem. Thanks for you help :D